# Counting Number of distinct paths if only diagonal and vertical moves are allowed

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to count the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$, ($n,k> 0$) when only diagonal and vertical moves are allowed. I know that if only horizontal and vertical moves are allowed than its $n+k \choose n$, but can it help solving the question?

edit: by diagonal moves I mean moves from $(x,y)$ to $(x+1,y+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is quite simple. Note that reaching from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ requires $n$ horizontal steps and $k$ vertical steps.

But, regardless of whether you take a vertical or a diagonal step, the $y$ coordinate of your position always increases by $1$. Therefore, it will take you exactly $k$ steps to reach your position.

But then, you can decide, out of these $k$ steps, which $n$ of these should be diagonal, and which should be only vertical.

Therefore, the following statement is true:

> A path from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ consists of exactly $k$ steps, exactly $n$ of which are diagonal steps.

Therefore, the answer is just $\binom kn$(exclaim).

Note : a similar argument applies for the only "horizontal and vertical steps allowed" problem, since there you must reach your target in $n+k$ steps, out which you can choose the $n$ horizontal, or $k$ vertical ones, giving the answer $\binom{n+k}{n} = \binom{n+k}{k}$.

Comment: The exclamation mark after the solution $(k,n)$ could be read as factorials ...

Comment: Oh, dear. What's a better way  to say it? There, got it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine a few cases to clarify.( Hereafter $D$  means diagonally right step and $U$ means vertically up step.)

It is also clearly visible that $n\le k$ to reach (n, k)  with given restrictions.

*Case 1*) When $n\neq k$

Consider for example $n=2$ and $k=3$ we can simply write out the ways to reach $(2,3)$ as $DUD,DDU,UDD$

Lets consider $n=2$ and $k=4$. Here too we simply write out the ways as $DUDU, DDUU, DUUD, UUDD,UDUD,UDDU$

Lets consider $n=1$ and $k=3$ . Here the ways are $DUU, UDU, UUD$

Hence after looking at some examples we simply that for $n\neq k$ the number of paths are $\binom {k}{n}$

*Case 2*) $n=q$

Using basic intuition we simply have only one way to go to the point $(n, n) $ with given restrictions which is by taking diagonal steps at every point. 
Hence we get $1=\binom {n}{n}$

Hence for generalized formula to reach $(n, k) $ where $n\le k$ with given restrictions is $\binom {k}{n}$